# I am developing an app to learn english with flutter. I have a problem with my android screen app

Tags: flutter

I am developing an app to learn English with flutter. I have a problem with my app when I ran it on Android devices( IOS is okay).

The problem is when I open my app and click on the button menu like Intermediate(to clarify my button still can't click, I just click on the screen) it will active my navigation bar on the phone first(like my screen is not active) and then I click it again it will be okay.

So I want to ask how I can change (or just a keyword) to get my button menu can click on the first time not click on my screen first?

[image]

[image]

The second time click is okay(screen is active or like that)

Answer (score 0):

I have already found my answers guys.
I just forgot to display my system bottom bar.
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays(SystemUiOverlay.values));